# Change "active" class in navbar on scrolling - JavaScript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I want to change the **active class** in **navbar** whenever a user **scrolls**. Like,
initially the Home element has active class and hence the background of **Home** is **violet**.
[image]

But as soon as I **scroll down** to the About Me section, I want the background of **Home** in navbar to be **white** and that of **About** to be **violet**.
[image]

But I'm not much experienced with JavaScript. I found a codepen in a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsPWEmfOQdU) which showed the navbar links changing the active class on scrolling.

Here's the codepen that I got from YouTube:
https://codepen.io/Web_Cifar/pen/LYRBbVE

That code snippet from YouTube:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll("nav .container ul li");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono";
  font-size: 24px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#home {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

#about {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#footer {
  background-color: crimson;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav .container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav .container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav .container ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: black;
}

nav .container ul li.active {
  background-color: crimson;
  transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}

nav .container ul li.active a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


/* ********************* */


/* This Code is for only the floating card in right bottom corner */


/* ********************** */

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--color-4);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#webCifar-sidebox {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow-x: clip;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#webCifar-sidebox p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#webCifar {
  --color-1: #17bcb4;
  --color-2: #24252a;
  --color-3: #244044;
  --color-4: #f3f8f7;
  background: var(--color-2);
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--color-4);
  padding: 10px 17px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100% + 5px));
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 5px));
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out transform;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out transform;
  z-index: 4;
}

#webCifar.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#webCifar .logo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#webCifar .author {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#webCifar .author span {
  background-color: var(--color-3);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#webCifar .items {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#webCifar .item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

#webCifar .item:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-3);
}

#webCifar svg {
  max-width: 20px;
}

#webCifar .close {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: var(--color-3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#webCifar-icon {
  --color-2: #24252a;
  --color-3: #244044;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  text-align: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: var(--color-2);
  color: white;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  right: -27%;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff7d;
}

#webCifar-icon svg {
  max-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="home active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="footer"><a href="#footer">Footer</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
</section>
<section id="footer">
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</section>

<!-- *******************   -->
<!--  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
<!--  This Code is for only the floating card in right bottom corner -->
<!-- ********************  -->

<div id="webCifar-sidebox">
  <div id="webCifar">
    <h2 class="logo">Web Cifar</h2>
    <p class="author">Coded By <span>Shaif Arfan</span> </p>
    <div class="items">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdxaLo9ALJgXgOUDURRPGiQ" target="_blank" class="item youtubeLink">
        <svg title="watch how we made this" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
          <path d="M10 12a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" />
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.458 10C1.732 5.943 5.522 3 10 3s8.268 2.943 9.542 7c-1.274 4.057-5.064 7-9.542 7S1.732 14.057.458 10zM14 10a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
        </svg>
        <p>Watch how we made this.
        </p>
      </a>
      <a href="https://webcifar.com" target="_blank" class="item">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 12a9 9 0 01-9 9m9-9a9 9 0 00-9-9m9 9H3m9 9a9 9 0 01-9-9m9 9c1.657 0 3-4.03 3-9s-1.343-9-3-9m0 18c-1.657 0-3-4.03-3-9s1.343-9 3-9m-9 9a9 9 0 019-9" />
        </svg>
        <p>https://webcifar.com</p>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="close">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="webCifar-icon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
    </svg>
    <p>Info About the pen</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my snippet:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .nav-container a");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@font-face {
  font-family: "neoneon";
  src: url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.ttf) format('truetype'), /* ../../<repo-name>Fonts/<font-name>.<format> is for using custom fonts on github*/
  url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(./Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.woff) format('woff'), /* ../Fonts/<font-name>.<format> is for using locally and on live server */
  url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.svg) format('svg'), url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(225, 0, 225, 0.469);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(225, 0, 225);
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px #88888853;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-container {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-container a {
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container .active {
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 225, 0.469);
}

.nav-container a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.265);
}

#brief {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 140px 0 140px;
  background-image: url('./Assets/images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#brief-container {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#brief-container .brief-pic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

#brief-container img {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
}

#brief-container .brief-text {
  background-color: white;
  gap: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -70px;
  padding: 90px 30px 40px;
}

#brief-container .brief-name {
  font-family: neoneon;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#brief-container .brief-name span,
#about .about-title span {
  color: rgb(225, 0, 225);
}

#brief-container .brief-description {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about {
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  gap: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

#about .about-title {
  font-family: neoneon;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#about .about-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about,
#projects,
#contact {
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <title>Web</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a class="brief active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
      <a class="project" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="brief">
    <div id="brief-container">
      <div class="brief-pic">
        <img src="./Assets/images/pfp.jpg" alt="profile picture">
      </div>
      <div class="brief-text">
        <div class="brief-name">
          Web <span>Web</span>
        </div>
        <div class="brief-description">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus molestiae sit earum consectetur quae id eius esse magnam hic, cumque, consequuntur numquam possimus doloremque rem vitae. Illo exercitationem accusantium laboriosam.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="about-title">
      About <span>Me</span>
    </div>
    <div class="about-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae ab consequatur, beatae architecto quidem sequi doloremque quam animi quasi est. Placeat impedit facere reiciendis ab deleniti, dolorum accusamus illo libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Recusandae, numquam quidem. Ratione qui neque esse aliquid quod impedit hic facilis aut, perspiciatis suscipit exercitationem sunt. Repudiandae ex accusamus blanditiis. Sed.</div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

So basically my HTML is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a class="brief active" href="#brief">Home</a>
      <a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
      <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="brief">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam facere unde itaque ea, minus commodi voluptate in a quibusdam minima dolores veniam, consectetur, quam eveniet architecto esse aut culpa iure!
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ipsa tenetur sapiente magnam, reprehenderit odit ex. Delectus laborum omnis laudantium ea recusandae nihil, sequi, atque voluptatem tenetur inventore vero voluptatibus.
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And JavaScript is:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .nav-container a");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
```

I've looked a lot but I'm unable to find a solution.

Please help me find and correct the error in my code.

Comment: When I review your CodePen and scroll down / up, it is working as you described. Please clarify what is not working in your code.

Comment: I said **that** codepen which meant the one from YouTube. I've edited the question and changed it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, got back to this project an encountered a problem with solution provided by @Gerard. I didn't notice this the last time, but the active class was being changed even before the particular section was on screen.
So I updated it as follows:

*script.js*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
  const navA = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .nav-container a");

  function updateActiveSection() {
    let maxVisibleArea = 0;
    let activeSection = null;

    sections.forEach((section) => {
      const visibleArea = getVisibleArea(section);

      if (visibleArea > maxVisibleArea) {
        maxVisibleArea = visibleArea;
        activeSection = section.getAttribute("id");
      }
    });

    navA.forEach((a) => {
      a.classList.remove("active");
      if (a.classList.contains(activeSection)) {
        a.classList.add("active");
      }
    });
  }

  function getVisibleArea(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const visibleHeight = Math.min(rect.bottom, windowHeight) - Math.max(rect.top, 0);
    const visibleWidth = Math.min(rect.right, windowWidth) - Math.max(rect.left, 0);
    return visibleHeight * visibleWidth;
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", updateActiveSection);
  window.addEventListener("resize", updateActiveSection);
};
// Rest of the code
```

*style.css*

```
html,
body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-container{
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-container a{
    padding: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container .active{
    background-color: rgba(225, 0, 225, 0.469);
}

.nav-container a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.265);
}
/* Rest of the code */
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <a class="brief active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
            <a class="project" href="#project">Projects</a>
            <a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="brief">
       <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </section>
    <section id="about">
       <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </section>
    <section id="project">
       <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </section>
    <section id="contact">
       <!-- Rest of the code -->
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This will keep the section class active until the one below or above takes up majority of the screen.

Check out its implementation on my [personal portfolio](https://pratham-jaiswal.cyclic.app/).

Check out the full code on my [github repo](https://github.com/pratham-jaiswal/personal-portfolio).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-x: hidden;` from `html` and `body`.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar .nav-container a");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@font-face {
  font-family: "neoneon";
  src: url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.ttf) format('truetype'), /* ../../<repo-name>Fonts/<font-name>.<format> is for using custom fonts on github*/
  url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(./Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.woff) format('woff'), /* ../Fonts/<font-name>.<format> is for using locally and on live server */
  url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.svg) format('svg'), url(../personal-portfolio/Assets/Fonts/Neoneon/Neoneon.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(225, 0, 225, 0.469);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(225, 0, 225);
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px #88888853;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-container {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-container a {
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container .active {
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 225, 0.469);
}

.nav-container a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.265);
}

#brief {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 140px 0 140px;
  background-image: url('./Assets/images/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#brief-container {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#brief-container .brief-pic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

#brief-container img {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
}

#brief-container .brief-text {
  background-color: white;
  gap: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: -70px;
  padding: 90px 30px 40px;
}

#brief-container .brief-name {
  font-family: neoneon;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#brief-container .brief-name span,
#about .about-title span {
  color: rgb(225, 0, 225);
}

#brief-container .brief-description {
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about {
  width: 70vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  gap: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

#about .about-title {
  font-family: neoneon;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#about .about-content {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about,
#projects,
#contact {
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <title>Web</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a class="brief active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="about" href="#about">About</a>
      <a class="project" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="brief">
    <div id="brief-container">
      <div class="brief-pic">
        <img src="./Assets/images/pfp.jpg" alt="profile picture">
      </div>
      <div class="brief-text">
        <div class="brief-name">
          Web <span>Web</span>
        </div>
        <div class="brief-description">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus molestiae sit earum consectetur quae id eius esse magnam hic, cumque, consequuntur numquam possimus doloremque rem vitae. Illo exercitationem accusantium laboriosam.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="about-title">
      About <span>Me</span>
    </div>
    <div class="about-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae ab consequatur, beatae architecto quidem sequi doloremque quam animi quasi est. Placeat impedit facere reiciendis ab deleniti, dolorum accusamus illo libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Recusandae, numquam quidem. Ratione qui neque esse aliquid quod impedit hic facilis aut, perspiciatis suscipit exercitationem sunt. Repudiandae ex accusamus blanditiis. Sed.</div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems to work in the snippet and codepen, but why is it not working in my browser when I'm running it from VSCode?

Comment: nevermind!! it works like a charm. I wrapped the JS code in `window.onload = function () { }` and it worked perfectly. Now the thing was the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsPWEmfOQdU) where I got this code from also used VSCode but he **didn't** wrap it around `window.onload = function () { }` or any such thing and it still worked for him

Comment: **Important Note:** `overflow-x: hidden;` should only be removed from `html` and not `body`. I added it to avoid horizontal scroll. Removing it from `html, body { }` and adding it just to the `body{ }` worked perfectly!!